# ansible: difference between a variable and a fact

Tags: ansible, variables

While I'm using Ansible for quite some time, I'm not sure I really understand the differences between a variable and a fact.

Would it be any difference doing

```yaml
- set_fact:
    nginx_ssl: /etc/nginx/ssl
    nginx_conf_file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

or

```yaml
  vars:
    nginx_ssl: /etc/nginx/ssl
    nginx_conf_file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Could someone explain me, possibly with an example where it really make a difference ?

Answer (score 6):

Ansible **facts** are data collected about the (target) systems on which Ansible takes actions. They are variables, but set by Ansible (in a way like ***system defined variables***). They are collected during `Gathering Facts` stage of a playbook run, and it is controlled by the `gather_facts` setting. Ansible calls this [variables discovered from systems](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id26). That said, it is possible to set custom facts also.

Some examples are:

- `ansible_hostname` - the FQDN of the target system
- `ansible_os_family` - the Operating System family of target system (RedHat, Debian, etc.)

The other **variables** are the ones we can set as per our requirement (in a way like ***user defined variables***).

Some examples are:

- `my_fav_fruits: [ 'orange', 'apple', 'banana' ]` - yours might differ.
- `config_dir: '/etc/my_app/conf.d'` - for my application configuration files.

---

**Update:**

*Updating answer to make it relevant to the edit(s) made in question.*

As [@Bruce Becker's answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12393/23904) rightly pointed out, there is a difference in the precedence of variables set with `set_fact`. Also variables that need to be set at "run time" can be set this way. Without further explanation, taking your example variables, if I create a play like below:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    nginx_ssl: '/etc/nginx/ssl'
    nginx_conf_file: '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'

  tasks:
  - name: set nginx path to /opt when running on Debian
    set_fact:
      nginx_ssl: '/opt/nginx/ssl'
      nginx_conf_file: '/opt/nginx/nginx.conf'
    when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
  - debug:
      msg: 'ssl: {{ nginx_ssl }} and conf: {{ nginx_conf_file }}'
```

Then the `set_fact` variables will take precedence (on Debian) and output will be:

```
"msg": "ssl: /opt/nginx/ssl and conf: /opt/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

On other distributions, it will be what was declared in `vars:`.

Comment: Understood the context now. I updated my answer too.

Comment: "On other distributions, it will be what was declared in vars:." I don't understand this statement. Why whould it be different on other distributions like Redhat for example?

Comment: The vars declared in the `vars:` section of the play have lower precedence than `set_fact`, so it will be what was declared under `vars:`, unless it is overridden with `set_fact` again for Redhat,

Answer (score 3):

Not to contradict anything written in [@Ceshadri_C's answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12389/354), but to focus more on the difference between facts and variables - perhaps the [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) page could be of greater insight.

**The difference between facts and variables set is defined by their precedence**, *i.e.* all variables are important, but some variables are more important than others. In your case, *the same variable* set as a fact (priority 19) would take precedence declared as a variable in a task (priority 17) or play (priority 12).

Answer (score 1):

Facts are also made available to subsequent plays. Variables are not.